# Page not found error if controller is lowercase but works if first letter is uppercase in Zend Framework app

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

this is weird I've been hacking away for a while at this error. It seems to show up only on the deployment server. I have a perfectly working controller named holidays - here is the structure of the controller and the view:

```
controllers
-> HolidaysController.php

<?php

class HolidaysController extends App_Controller_Action {

  public function indexAction() {
.....
  }
}

?>
```

My views file is in

```
views/scripts/holidays/index.phtml
```

when I navigate to `website.com/holidays` it give me this error:

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
Stack trace:

#0 /home/bookitfa/bookings/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(515): Zend_Controller_Action->__call('indexAction', Array)
#1 /home/bookitfa/bookings/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#2 /home/bookitfa/bookings/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#3 /home/bookitfa/bookings/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#4 /home/bookitfa/bookings/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#5 /home/bookitfa/bookings/public/index.php(29): Zend_Application->run()
#6 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'holidays',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

But when I navigate to `website.com/Holidays` it works for some odd reason. All other controllers work fine except this certain controller seems to only work if the controller name has the first letter uppercase. Why is that? This is a zend framework based application. All my urls would be out of place like this.
EDIT =======

The strange paart is that irrespective of what I keep the filename i.e HolidaysController.php or holidaysController.php - online I can only access it by /Holidays and not by /holidays, this is a very serious issue here and I've run out of ideas on how to resolve it :(

Comment: What is `App_Controller_Action`? Does it extend `Zend_Controller_Action`?

Comment: Yes the App_Controller_Action is an extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names in Zend are case sensitive - on Linux.

Why? Because it only loads the class file it needs, and file names on Linux are case sensitive.

You're probably dev'ing on Windows, which is not case sensitive. When asking for file "holidaysController.php" windows will return HolidaysController.php, holidayscontroller.php or HoLiDaYsCoNtRoLlEr.php - you get the idea! It looks for the file, then loads only that file.

On Linux (and Mac) those 4 filenames are all different. Even though you've named the class according to the docs (upper case for classes, camel for actions) you need to also call the router with the same case - otherwise the file won't be found and loaded.

Why it gets confusing: Zend tries to normlise to lower case so it's looking for "holidayController.php" first (when you enter "Holiday"). It gets a bit complicated with mixed cases: see the yellow box on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.basics.html) : so it failed to find the normlaised so is treating as mixed case, which then works. When you enter "holiday" it fails to find the file, but as it's not been normalised or camelcase, it doesn't need ot look for any other file. It just fails.

Your options: stay with "Holidays" as the route for that file, or rename the file as "holidayController.php" and you can run with Holiday or holiday. (Leave the class as HolidayController - that bit is not case sensitive).

Comment: Didn't work :( this is getting on my nerves now - any other idea? I renamed the file but its still not working

Comment: You renamed as "holidayController.php" and /holiday/ failed? OK - something else juicy is hapenning. As Phil suggested (plus noted the last time you posted this question) what is App_Controller_Action - you have defined that as an extension of Zend_Controller_Action?

Comment: Yes - the weird thing is that this is all working on my localhost, infact all of my other controllers are working except for this one. They're all named the same way - I'm really lost here :(

Comment: Can you post all the controller file (start to end) on a fiddle somewhere? I'm otherwise stuck as lowercase should sort it out. It shouldn't matter, but you did rename the file and not have both uploaded?

Comment: I did the renaming however it still didn't work I'll post it right now and show you my code

Comment: And App_Controller_Action? And I assume that you did upload as "holidayController.php" - this is still upper case according to the filename.

Comment: Yes thats the exact file name - the thing is that all of my controller files are named the same way example I have a PropertiesController.php file which is accessed using/properties a TariffsController.php file accessed using /tariffs - I dont get it why its all changed for the HolidaysController.php file...

Comment: Its uploaded as HolidaysController.php - same case as all mu other controllers

Comment: You can check my gist for the app_controller_action

Comment: All my other  controllers extend the same app_controller_action and no one has any issues

Comment: Does your holiday factory also load a file? Check lowercase vs upper case filenames on that one.

Comment: WHOA! I think I found the issue - I just disabled permissions via ACL and it ran - there must be something wrong there. Thanks guys - I'll be back on  anew thread if thats the case!!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted after so long!